# If I own an ADS in a company that is delisted, can I exchange my ADS with shares of the same company in their original market?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, international, adr, hong-kong

Assume that I own some NYSE:CHA ([American depositary shares (ADSs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_depositary_receipt) for [China Telecom Corp. Ltd.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Telecom)), which is [scheduled to be delisted from NYSE sometime between Jan. 7 and Jan. 11, 2021](https://finance.yahoo.com/amphtml/news/china-warns-retaliation-nyses-delisting-112950731.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210102231442/https://finance.yahoo.com/amphtml/news/china-warns-retaliation-nyses-delisting-112950731.html)). Can I exchange these ADS with shares of the same company in their original market (viz., [SEHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Stock_Exchange): 728)?